# Get SubTypes in Java with Reflections library

Tags: java, reflection

I try to get classes that implements an interface in a given package, using [reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections).

I have the following code :

```
package TestClass;

import org.reflections.Reflections;

import org.reflections.scanners.SubTypesScanner;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;

public class Checks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("TestReflection.src.testclass");
        try{
            Set<Class<? extends CheckingClass>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(CheckingClass.class);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me this error : `org.reflections.ReflectionsException: Scanner SubTypesScanner was not configured`

It surprises me because i got the code from an example of how to use reflections library, so it should work. 
The library, i think, is well imported because other methods work. 
I've tried a lot of things and can't make this code work.

Maybe i'm missing an important details. Any idea?

Thanks

EDIT : Here's the tree of my project, so you can see if my path is good :

[image]

EDIT 2 : I changed

`Reflections reflections = new Reflections("TestReflection.src.testclass", new SubTypesScanner());`

to

`Reflections reflections = new Reflections("testclass", new SubTypesScanner());`

and i have an other error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile
    at org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.getOrCreateClassObject(JavassistAdapter.java:107)
    at org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.getOrCreateClassObject(JavassistAdapter.java:34)
    at org.reflections.scanners.AbstractScanner.scan(AbstractScanner.java:28)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:270)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:216)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:137)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:182)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:155)
    at testclass.Checks.main(Checks.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.bytecode.ClassFile
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 9 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You should follow the standard naming conventions. `TestReflection.src.TestClass` doesn’t look like a valid package name, but since you are also using uppercase letters in your `package TestClass;`, we can’t really know.

Comment: I changed `TestClass` to `testclass` but i don't think it changes anything

Comment: Don’t program by Trial and Error. Try to *understand* what you are doing. 1) `new Reflections("...")` expects a **package** name. What is the name of your package? Do you even understand what a Java package is? (Hint: you have a `package` declaration at the beginning of your source file). 2) Java identifiers are case sensitive, even when the Windows file system is not. You should match the folder name and the package declaration. As said, the standard convention is to use lowercase letters. 3) Artifacts of your IDE project like `TestReflection` and `src` folder do not belong to the Java code.

Comment: @Holger 
1. My package name is testclass, this is why i changed my code in the second edit, and i get a new error. I know what a package is now. 
2. The folder name and the package declaration match, it shouldn't be a problem. 
3. Ok, so the code in my second edit should be good. So i need to focus on this new error message.

Comment: The folder name is `testclass`, which matches the string `"testclass"`, which is going into the right direction. The declaration in your source file still is `package TestClass;`, which doesn’t match, though that’s `Checks.java` which doesn’t preclude that at least one source file uses a correct `package testclass;` and since Windows is not case sensitive, all class files will go into the same output folder. But you should make sure that all use the correct `package testclass;`, to avoid future problems.

Comment: The new error is indeed something entirely different. Seem this Reflections library uses [Javassist](https://www.javassist.org/), but you have to install it manually.

Comment: @Holger Indeed, i installed Javassist and it now works, thank you very much.